# How to send packets at 512 nano sec delay using Socket Programming and UDP socket

Tags: networking, c, wireshark, sockets

Using `SOCK_DGRAM` for `UDP` sockets

All packets are `22 bytes` in length (ie `64 including headers`)

**client.c**

```
...
    no_of_packets--;
    sprintf(buf, "#:!0 rem");
    sprintf(buf, format , buf);
    sprintf(buf_aux, "#: 0 rem");
    sprintf(buf_aux, format , buf_aux);
    buf[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
    buf_aux[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
    len = strlen(buf) + 1;
    send(s, buf, len, 0);
    while (no_of_packets-- > 1) {
        nanosleep(&T, NULL);
        send(s, buf, len, 0);
    }
    send(s, buf_aux, len, 0);
```

**server.c**

```
...
while(1) {
        if (len = recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)){
            // do nothing
        }
}
```

When I open `Wireshark` to see avg delay between the packets which are sent,

I can see the following:

- *MIN* delay:  0.000 006 795 sec => *6 micro sec*
- *MAX* delay:  0.000 260 952 sec => *260 micro sec*
- But I want to send packets every *512 nano sec* (ie., 0.512 micro sec).

> **How** can I achieve this speed?

Comment: the overheads of nanosleep make what you want not possible. Try to eliminate it and use a time wasting loop. i.e. eliminate the CPU yielding step included in nanosleep. First do not have any loop at all to determine what your lower limit actually is. Eliminate the scheduler via forcing CPU affinity with `tasket -c 2 ./client` and set the CPU frequency scaling governor to performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The problem with nanosleep is that it includes rather significant overhead. Users tend to expect accurate delays down to very low values, which isn't really practical for the CPU yielding sleep routine. The expectation is this:

```
actual delay = nanosleep(requested delay)
```

whereas, in reality users get this:

```
actual delay = nanosleep(requested delay) + the fixed overheads.
```

On my test computer, with forced CPU affinity (to remove scheduler effects) and the CPU frequency scaling governor set to performance, the fixed overheads are 52 microseconds.

A possible solution for your problem is to replace the call to nanosleep with a delay loop. Then the CPU would not yield, going into idle, nor incur operating system call 
overheads. Of course, a delay loop can be difficult to calibrate as to actually get the desired delay. I made two programs, one using nanosleep and one using a delay loop to demonstrate. In order to make other overheads negligible, the sleep and delay loops are run a great many times for each time and print type calls:

[image]

For reference, the programs used:

nanosleep version:

```
/*****************************************************************************
*
* test_slp2.c 2019.09.18 Smythies
*       Create data to determine the lower limit of nanosleep.
*
* test_slp.cpp 2017.11.25 Smythies
*       Of course, none of this stuff works the way it used to.
*
* test_slp.cpp 2012.01.24 Smythies
*          I need to be able to yeild (sleep), but for less than a second.
*          Experiment with nanosleep and usleep functions.
*
*****************************************************************************/

// prevent warning about nanosleep
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CR 13

unsigned long long stamp(void){
   struct timeval tv;

   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

   return (unsigned long long)tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
} /* endprocedure */

int main(){
   unsigned long long start, now;
   long i, j, k;
   int ns;
   struct timespec time;

   time.tv_sec = 0;
   start = stamp();
   for(ns = 500; ns < 100000; ns = ns + 500){
      for(j = 0; j < 100000; j++){
         time.tv_nsec = ns;
         nanosleep(&time, &time);
      } /* endfor */
      now = stamp();
      printf("%d %llu\n", ns, (now - start));
      start = now;
   } /* endfor */
   return(0);
}
```

And the delay loop version, including a crude calibration, which the graph shows, is not great:

```
/*****************************************************************************
*
* test_slp3.c 2019.09.18 Smythies
*       Now, do the same as test_slp2, but use a waste time loop instead of
        nanosleep.
*
* test_slp2.c 2019.09.18 Smythies
*       Create data to determine the lower limit of nanosleep.
*
* test_slp.cpp 2017.11.25 Smythies
*       Of course, none of this stuff works the way it used to.
*
* test_slp.cpp 2012.01.24 Smythies
*          I need to be able to yeild (sleep), but for less than a second.
*          Experiment with nanosleep and usleep functions.
*
*****************************************************************************/

// prevent warning about nanosleep
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* for my test computer */
#define CALIBRATION 26

unsigned long long stamp(void){
   struct timeval tv;

   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

   return (unsigned long long)tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
} /* endprocedure */

int main(){
   unsigned long long start, now;
   long i, j, k, m, loops;
   int ns;
   struct timespec time;

   time.tv_sec = 0;
   start = stamp();
   for(ns = 500; ns <= 10000; ns = ns + 100){
      loops = ns * CALIBRATION / 50;  /* will have rounding issues */
      for(m = 0; m < 10000000; m++){ /* this is just to slow things down, so we can test */
         for(j = 0; j < loops; j++){
            k = j;  /* make sure any compile optimizer doesn't take out the loop */
         } /* endfor */
      } /* endfor */
      now = stamp();
      printf("%d %llu\n", ns, (now - start));
      start = now;
   } /* endfor */
   return(0);
}
```

Anticipated question: Why no gettimeofday jitter in the delay loop test, when you (I) claim it is the reason for the jitter in the nanosleep version?
Answer: Possibly becuase the delay loop method ran for much longer per sample than the nanosleep version. Or, I was wrong.

CPU affinity was forced for these tests. i.e.:

```
time taskset -c 3 ./test_slp3
```

I timed the overall test just as a sanity check, as the sum of the individual times should equal the overall time. They did.

The CPU frequency scaling governor was set to performance:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer.